# How to create company profile on Bloomberg Business to get a high DA backlink?

Tags: backlinks

I have found that several companies in my niche created their profile on Bloomberg Business. They have also added the link to their website there. The links, in most cases, are one of the top 5 backlinks, as shown on Alexa.

I would like to create a profile for my company as well with a view to creating a high DA backlink. But how can I do it? There is no "Register" or "Add Your Business" options on Bloomberg Business.

Comment: Two things: Alexa is junk- do not pay attention to it. Also, there is an authority cap along with link quality scores that creates a natural curve in the algo. The notion that a PR 6 page with 2 links passes PR 3 per link has never been correct nor is it even close. Many times moderately ranked pages can pass much more value assuming the quality of the link itself. Chase good link opportunities where you find them. It is a bit of a misnomer that you must chase high value links exclusively. Please understand that I am not saying that this is not a good link opportunity.

Comment: So far I know, Google has stopped updating Page Rank (PR). So, we should avoid using it in determining value of links. Instead, we should use Domain Authority (DA). And yes, Alexa can be junk. But the top 5 backlinks, which it shows, possess a high DA. So, those links possesses some great opportunities in taking our website to a higher position in SERP.

Comment: Yeah. Stop chasing this too much. The SEO business is designed to keep you suckered into their line of offerings... MOZ is another one. This is not to say that MOZ is not valuable. They just have an agenda. Again, there are authority caps (in Google) and a link value ranges from 0 - .9 so doing the math, what is passed from high authority sites is not what you were lead to believe. Just chose good sites and create a good link with semantic signals in content if possible and all will be fine. Do not stress over all this back link stuff too much. Google prefers natural organic links anyway.

Comment: Your right i was try ed to update my business profile there, but there no option is available for add business/link

Comment: Where are you guys seeing this business profile? Is it this business search? http://www.bloomberg.com/research/common/symbollookup/symbollookup.asp The link to the company there is `nofollow` if thats the case, which is more or less worthless for SEO.